# Place holder is white and wont show letters on signup form

Tags: html, placeholder

So i have setup a website, and the login form to allow users to login to there cpanel is a little messed up heres what it looks like

[image]

[image]

as you can see if i copy it all, they letters are there, but for some reason the letters wont show

```
<!-- Login Client -->
      <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://cpanel.clearhostsolutions.com/auth" method="post">
      <div class="jBar">
          <div class="container">            
              <div class="row">                
                  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                      <h1>Client Login</h1>
                      <form>
                          <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                          <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" required>
                          <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign in">
                      </form>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4 contact_info">
                      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                      <ul>
                          <li><span>Call Now:</span>55-5698-4589</li>
                          <li><span>Email Adress: </span><a href="#">support@clearhostsolutions.com</a></li>
                          <li><span>Address Info:</span> Av new stret - New York</li>
                      </ul>                    
                  </div>                
                  <p class="jTrigger downarrow">Close</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <span class="jRibbon jTrigger up">Login to Cpanel</span>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <!-- End Login Client -->
```

Comment: What color have you specified for the text in your CSS?  Looks like white on white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong in your code but you can always change the placeholders color.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999 !important;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    opacity: 1 !important; // FF has reduced opacity on default
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999 !important;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
form input, form textarea, form select {
    color:#000;
}
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to use `!important` but see if that makes a difference.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yWXjm/)**

Comment: Ahh okay i see and where does that go? in the style.css? or would that just go in the HTML part with the rest of the code?

Comment: Okay thanks and can i just drop that anywhere in the style.css??? and even the :: ???

Comment: hello it seemed to have worked.. but only made the placeholder font more bold

Comment: http://gyazo.com/d83b1ddf5957db63754c837ff848b332 for some reason when i type its just not showing anything its like it has white font!! see the picture i linked :) i will accept it once it works thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by it is not showing anything because the screenshot looks fine!

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but its still not coming up black http://gyazo.com/a56d9a50500ac1e7f26f208ec8f3a64f i have typed in the password colum to.. and you cant see what should be black circles right?

Comment: so this is what i mean, i should be able to see what im typing like this http://gyazo.com/84224679ec00a69940237ba8f19da3fb instead its not actually showing up

Comment: Something is wrong in your code which is preventing it to be normal color... works fine in the JSFiddle

Comment: Hm i see what would you suggest?

Comment: Do as I suggested first

Comment: im sorry i dont know what !Important is, where do i put this?

Comment: Did you type the text you selected on username field? It seems like it's not a placeholder problem, change the `color` property of that field for something different from "white".

Comment: Yes i typed the text on the username field and then highlighted it also im not sure where the color property is..

Comment: There's no need to change the color of the placeholder. As you can see in his screenshots, the placeholders are OK (see "Your Password" text). It's necessary to change the color of the `input` field itself (again, not its placeholder).

Comment: I am sorry, I went along with the placeholder... thought your placeholder wasn't working... Will update answer

Comment: and how would i change the color of the input field?

Comment: @ClearHost - mandatory read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started :)

Comment: so i done this http://gyazo.com/fd630b5c2e019b0ac3be868ebd6d1888 and then i tried it again http://gyazo.com/880feb836a857af65d5ede84cc3d0c90 the password has text in it but is not highlighted, the username is highlighted without highlighting its just doing what the password does

Comment: Replace `color:#000;` with `color:#000 !important;`.

Comment: Do you know how to use [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If you could post your code there it would be easier to help you...

Comment: I only posted a little bit of the HTML i could send you the hole thing but only added what i thought would be affected and also posted the CSS into JSFiddle never used it before if i done something wrong let me know! http://jsfiddle.net/PaPu6/

Comment: Here it's showing the text normally. @imbondbaby answer would never work because your input is not of `type="text"`, it's an `email` input! Replace `input[type="text"] { color:#000 !important; }` with `form input, form textarea, form select { color:#000; }`

Comment: @Danguilherme Ah! I see what you are saying... updated it! thank you